# "document_start" for Firefox addon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I come from Chrome extensions, so I'm used to defining when a file should be injected by setting `run_at`, e.g., to `document_start` for injection before DOM construction. Is there an equivalent for Firefox addons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the equivalent would be the [`content-document-global-created` notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents). An extension can add an observer for that notification and then do something with the window - like injecting a content script. See [How to override JS function from a firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664478/785541) for one example of using this notification.

If you use the Add-on SDK it will do this job for you. The [`page-mod` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) supports a `contentScriptWhen` parameter - you can use `"start"` as its value and the content script will be injected before any page scripts get a chance to run.