# Does userscript work for a localhost html file

Tags: javascript, dom, userscripts

i have a html file namely "**http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/example.html**"

This file has the following content

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>HELLO WORLD</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var f = document.createElement("div");
    f.innerHTML="sfsdfsdfsdfsdf";
    document.body.insertBefore(f, document.body.firstChild);
    document.write("<a href='http://www.google.com'>sada</a> ");
   console.log("Program")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i use userscript mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083010/log-a-web-pages-dynamically-created-dom-elements-with-a-userscript) in this page it is not showing the div tag created. is this the problem with my localhost

The userscript i have written is taken from this [**LINK --- PLEASE GO THROUGH THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083010/log-a-web-pages-dynamically-created-dom-elements-with-a-userscript) you will find the `addJS_Node` function

Comment: Does your userscript has `@include http://localhost:8084/` line?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>HELLO WORLD</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var f = document.createElement("div");
        f.innerHTML="sfsdfsdfsdfsdf";
        document.body.insertBefore(f, document.body.firstChild);
        document.write("<a href='http://www.google.com'>sada</a> ");
        //document.body.innerHTML="<a href='http://www.google.com'>sada</a> ";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to insert newly created element somewhere, i.e. inside body element. So I had to move the script a little bit down, so body exists. Notice also that I commented out your line with innerHTML property, to not overwrite what is already in body tag.

It will work on localhost, as there is no connection between your problem and running locally.

Comment: i tried the above code but unfortunately it is not working for me

Comment: i think the script in userscript is getting added after the script here that is why the hook for document.createElement is not working Even though i mentioned // @run-at      document-start in the userscript but the script is being added at the end can any one resolve this

Comment: No, the script gets added before, as you can see from examining the page code in the browser.  It just takes a fraction of a second to take effect, by which time, some follow-on JS has already executed.

Comment: how did you try this code, that it doesnt work? did you use it as standalone html file, or did you paste it into existing one?

Comment: I pasted this code into existing one.  i tested it by placing `console.log("program");` in script tag hereand `console.log("userscript");` in userscript; program is printed first in console than userscript with this i came to a conclusion that the script in html file is executed first than userscript

Comment: `<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>HELLO WORLD</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var f = document.createElement("div");
        f.innerHTML="sfsdfsdfsdfsdf";
        document.body.insertBefore(f, document.body.firstChild);
        document.write("<a href='http://www.google.com'>sada</a> ");
       console.log("Program")
    </script>
</body>
</html>` I included `console.log("userscript");` below the  `addJS_Node (null, null, LogNewTagCreations);`  in the above mentioned userscript

Comment: what is addJS Node ? Can you paste ALL the code with inclusions you made? With console.log("userscript") and addJS Node? Also I think you should paste this code in question, under EDIT label, so formatting will work, because now I had to struggle formatting it. I really want to help you, but what you pasted is not enough... for now I see only code I provided and "Program" string in console output

Comment: i have edited the question please go through it. Thank you so much for your concern.

Comment: I dont see all the pasted code in question... there is no userscript you are talking about. Im tryin' to help but you really need to provide all the details I need.

Comment: The userscript is present in the LINK please go through it

Comment: Please go through the Userscript given in the LINK i tried the exact script on this html file

Comment: @Carlos Please copy the userscript and run it on localhost file we are not getting any output

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the issues that Carlos pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10191372/331508), it appears that that code it just not fast enough to catch everything on a simple, local page.  Sorry about that. When I tested it, I used my test server.

If you point your script at [Carlos's version of the test page, hosted at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/aracuw), the script catches the `createElement()` calls in that case.

It's a race, and that's just about the best Greasemonkey can do.  As [already stated (7th comment down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185588/how-to-retrieve-dynamically-created-tags-from-a-webpage-using-userscript#comment-13078918), Greasemonkey is not the best tool for the job you are trying to do.

Comment: I am not getting output for the Carlos's version of the test page. Please tell me how you got it.

Comment: My apologies.  I checked again (with newer versions of FF and GM) and the script only shows the tags that were added after the `DOMContentLoaded` event.  Once again, **GREASEMONKEY IS NOT THE RIGHT TOOL FOR YOUR DESIRED TASK.**

Comment: Then how can we add a script as extension to ff or chrome. we thought of using userscript because it has //@run-at document-start but now this is not working how can we achieve this. PLease help us

Comment: This is not a trivial problem.  See [“document_start” for Firefox addon?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8744726/331508), and the linked posts, for a start on the *first piece* of a solution.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but i didn't get it. can i convert the above userscript into a .js file and convert into an extension so that my problem gets solved.

Comment: No.  You will need to write an extension from scratch.  Or find an extension that does some of what you want, and examine and modify its code.  There is no magic bullet, right now. This is not a trivial problem.

Comment: can i go for a content script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10456/discussion-between-user1275375-and-brock-adams)